# Spring data rest. How to take repository class through request URI

Tags: spring-data-rest

Can anyone help me please.

I have a few entities and repositories inside my app which is based on spring data rest.
Right now I wrote my own HandlerInterceptor implementation to do preHandling each request and I have to know which repository will use for each http request.

Ofc I can make separate Interceptor for each repository but this solution is not flexible Any ideas?

Thx for advance

Answer (score 2):

Repositories are resolved in spring data-rest using the [Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/support/Repositories.html) class.

The repositories class exposes a helper method ([`getRepositoryFor(Class<?>)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/support/Repositories.html#getRepositoryFor-java.lang.Class-))  for finding the repository for a given class.

You can use the following snippet for finding a repository for a given class in your interceptor:

```
Repositories repositories = new Repositories(appContext);
repositories.getRepositoryFor(entityObject.getClass());
```

A more elegant solution would be to take advantage of the built-in spring-data-rest repository lookup implementation with a custom controller(RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver)

For this you just need to add a [`RootResourceInformation`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RootResourceInformation.html) parameter to a RepositoryRestController endpoint method.

```
        @RepositoryRestController
        @RequestMapping("/customName")
        public class RepositoryExportController {

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext appContext;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{repository}",
                    produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
            public Resources<Resource<?>> export(RootResourceInformation resourceInformation, ...) {

         Repositories repositories = new Repositories(appContext);

         CrudRepository repo=(CrudRepository)repositories.getRepositoryFor(resourceInformation.getDomainType());

          repo.findAll();
         ...other logic....
     }
```

Comment: Great Answer! This allowed me to implement a proper controller method for spring-security-acl as a sub-resource.